# Adding object to an Arraylist of Arraylist [Hash Merge]

Tags: java, arraylist, hash

I am having issues adding an object to an Arraylist of Arraylist.

```
//instantiate Bucket List
ArrayList< ArrayList<Block> > rBucketlist = new ArrayList< ArrayList<Block> >(M-1);
for (int i=0; i<M-1; i++) {
    rBucketlist.add(bucket);
}
```

after that when I attempt to add a Block into rBucketlist:

```
RelationLoader rLoader=relR.getRelationLoader();
    //hash phase(R)
    while(rLoader.hasNextBlock()){
        mBuffer=rLoader.loadNextBlocks(1);
        mBuff=mBuffer[0];
        for (int tt=0; tt<mBuff.getNumTuples(); tt++){
            Tuple temp = mBuff.tupleLst.get(tt); 
            mod = temp.key%(M-1);//19 buckets allowed

            if (mainmemBuffer[mod].getNumTuples()==10){
                rBucketlist.get(mod).add(mainmemBuffer[mod]);
                mainmemBuffer[mod].tupleLst.clear();
                mainmemBuffer[mod].insertTuple(temp);
            }
            else{
                mainmemBuffer[mod].insertTuple(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am having trouble on the line `rBucketlist.get(mod).add(mainmemBuffer[mod]);`
instead of adding on block, I seem to be adding more than one block (not of size 10)

How is that possible?

Comment: Can you add more details about what is not working?

Comment: instead of adding one block of size 10. It is adding other blocks in (size <10)...

Answer (score 0):

Your "Instantiate bucket list" code is putting a reference to the same bucket into every position of rBucketlist.  As a result, when you add a `Block` to one bucket, it looks like you are adding it to all buckets because it's all the same bucket.

Try this:

```
//instantiate Bucket List
ArrayList< ArrayList<Block> > rBucketlist = new ArrayList< ArrayList<Block> >(M-1);
for (int i=0; i<M-1; i++) {
    rBucketlist.add(new ArrayList<Block>());  // <-- make a new list every time
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help! That worked (partially)... Another issue is that, when I try to add to that new Arraylist each time at this line: rBucketlist.get(mod).add(mainmemBuffer[mod]) I am also passing in a reference to mainmemBuffer[mod]. How can I copy in the content instead? As once I clear the buffer my content in the rBucketlist is replaced as well...